Circuit breaker selection and panel design for LED lighting fixtures

This drawing was made for LED lighting fixtures. The fixtures will operate at 230V and have a power factor of >0.95. The current in each branch should be around 2-3 amperes. I don't understand how this would protect the LEDs from overload. The circuit breakers seem oversized at 1x16A type C.
Wouldn't it make more sense if inrush current limiters were used in combination with 1x6A type B circuit breakers? When I asked the engineer who drew this circuit, he said that the standard (turkish standard) mandates the usage of 1x16A as the minimum for lighting applications.

Circuit breakers are not there to protect the LED lamps.
Circuit breakers are there to prevent fires.
The wiring has a certain current rating.  If you push more current through the wire than that, then the wire will get hot and burn.
The circuit breaker is matched to the current rating of the wiring, not the current draw of the load (the lights.)
If a short circuit occurs anywhere in the lamp or the wiring, the circuit breaker will cut off the current before the wire can get hot enough to burn.

what protects the Lamps then from overcurrent ?

The design of the lamps protects them from overcurrent. The LED driver inside might have an overcurrent shutdown or upper current limit built into it but at its most basic form, a lamp is a LED and a current regulator. If the lamp is trying to draw more current than normal, one of these pieces is already broken.

@MECHA:  The LEDs are not simply connected to the mains.  There is a current regulator circuit inside either the socket or the bulb to limit the current to the LEDs.

@vir: Makes sense but moderately sizing the circuit breaker can allow it to work both as a second line of defense in case the Led driver malfunctions or fails and as protection for the led driver itself. Also, the inrush current limiter can prolong the life of the Led drivers.

If the LED driver malfunctions and fails then there is nothing to protect except for the wiring. Yes, you could make the case that it would be possible for it to fail in such a way that it would internally short and leave the LEDs intact but repairing that would be unrealistic. Also, not all devices work well with ICLs.

@vir: ok. there is also no surge protector in the circuit, can the driver itself handle this?
